# Foot arches flatten during lunges

Tags: foot

I find my right foot arch tends to flatten during lunges. How can I hold my arches? Any cues?

There is no pain associated with this.

I have imbalance of strength in both hips and legs. So, I incorporated single leg exercises in addition to squats and deadlifts....

Comment: Do you have any pain because of the flattening? Where? You could get shoes with arch support, it certainly helped me with leg pain when running.

Comment: flattening doesn't cause any pain - edited the question now. I was only wondering if it has something to do with improper form

Answer (score 2):

As long as there is no pain and your knee stays in line with your foot(push you knee out), you are probably good to go. If you do experience pain or discomfort, you shold buy a pair of weightlifting shoes. It is good to use anyway, as it improves posture during all kinds of leg exercises.

Comment: Weightlifting shoes are not necessary for lunges.